# Pyflakes and mixed Python codebases

Tags: python, pyflakes

I have a code base (C++, Python) with Python 2 and Python 3 scripts scattered throughout the source code.

I'd like to run pyflakes (and pytest from within pyflakes) against various subdirectories in the code base, but when I run pyflakes from Python 2 it fails on the Python 3 scripts.

Is there a clean way to run pyflakes against a mixed Python 2 and Python 3 code base?